# Scrapy Drop Empty Rows From CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, scrapy

I have written a scrapy script that scrapes a table and returns a csv, with a bit of help from pandas. However, the final csv always has several empty rows that I have to delete manually.

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd

class XGSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'expectedGoals'

    start_urls = [
        'https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/schedule/Premier-League-Scores-and-Fixtures',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        matches = []

        for row in response.xpath('//*[@id="sched_ks_3232_1"]//tbody/tr'):

            match = {
                'home': row.xpath('td[4]//text()').extract_first(),
                'homeXg': row.xpath('td[5]//text()').extract_first(),
                'score': row.xpath('td[6]//text()').extract_first(),
                'awayXg': row.xpath('td[7]//text()').extract_first(),
                'away': row.xpath('td[8]//text()').extract_first()
            }

            matches.append(match)

        x = pd.DataFrame(
            matches, columns=['home', 'homeXg', 'score', 'awayXg', 'away'])

        yield x.to_csv("xG.csv", sep=",", index=False)
```

with the `x` pandas dataframe, I have tried `x.dropna()` but that doesn't seem to remove any of the empty values. Here's an example of the first 15 rows of the dataframe:

```
print(x.head(15))

              home homeXg score awayXg             away
0        Liverpool    1.8   4–1    1.0     Norwich City
1         West Ham    0.8   0–5    3.0  Manchester City
2          Burnley    0.6   3–0    0.9      Southampton
3          Watford    1.0   0–3    0.6         Brighton
4      Bournemouth    1.1   1–1    1.0    Sheffield Utd
5   Crystal Palace    0.7   0–0    0.8          Everton
6        Tottenham    2.4   3–1    0.7      Aston Villa
7    Newcastle Utd    0.5   0–1    0.9          Arsenal
8   Leicester City    0.6   0–0    0.7           Wolves
9   Manchester Utd    2.3   4–0    0.9          Chelsea
10            None   None  None   None             None
11         Arsenal    0.9   2–1    1.4          Burnley
12     Southampton    1.6   1–2    1.5        Liverpool
13    Norwich City    1.5   3–1    0.7    Newcastle Utd
14        Brighton    1.8   1–1    0.8         West Ham
```

I think the `match` object is returning `None` for any empty values that have been scraped. Do you know how to yield a final csv with no empty rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first replace all None values with Nan using, (if it is the object None not the string 'None')

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = x.fillna(value=np.nan)
```

then delete all rows that have empty data using

```
x.dropna(

    axis=0,
    how='all', #use 'any' if you want remove rows with even one empty value
    inplace=True

)
```

[Read more about dropna() here](https://hackersandslackers.com/pandas-dataframe-drop/)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to skip `match` with `None` value(s), for example add this condition:

```py
if match['home']:
    matches.append(match)
```

output:

```py
              home homeXg score awayXg             away
0        Liverpool    1.8   4-1    1.0     Norwich City
1         West Ham    0.8   0-5    3.0  Manchester City
2          Burnley    0.6   3-0    0.9      Southampton
3          Watford    1.0   0-3    0.6         Brighton
4      Bournemouth    1.1   1-1    1.0    Sheffield Utd
5   Crystal Palace    0.7   0-0    0.8          Everton
6        Tottenham    2.4   3-1    0.7      Aston Villa
7    Newcastle Utd    0.5   0-1    0.9          Arsenal
8   Leicester City    0.6   0-0    0.7           Wolves
9   Manchester Utd    2.3   4-0    0.9          Chelsea
10         Arsenal    0.9   2-1    1.4          Burnley
11     Southampton    1.6   1-2    1.5        Liverpool
12    Norwich City    1.5   3-1    0.7    Newcastle Utd
13        Brighton    1.8   1-1    0.8         West Ham
14         Everton    0.9   1-0    1.1          Watford
```

Answer (score 1):

Just exclude `spacer` rows from your XPath (they have `class="spacer partial_table"`):

```
for row in response.xpath('//*[@id="sched_ks_3232_1"]//tbody/tr[not(@class)]'):
```